# Not receiving any data from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I setup a GA property:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-2', { 
‘anonymize_ip’: true });
</script>
```

However I'm not seeing any hits show up in Realtime, even when I manually trigger the URLs.  Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 3):

I had `‘` instead of `'` around `anonymize_ip`.  Thus the syntax highlighting around `anonymize_ip` is different in the code snippet.  This kept the script from firing.

Heads up when copying the snippet from Googles documentation page.